# how to display dynamic string value in struts treenode tag using java

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, treenode

below is my sample.jsp my requirement is to display tree structure format.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%
  String s="ROOT";
  %>
  <s:tree theme="ajax" id="root" label="%{s}"> 
  <s:treenode theme="ajax" id="child1" label="<b>Child 1</b>" />
  <s:treenode theme="ajax" id="subchild1" label="SubChild 1">
  <s:treenode theme="ajax" id="subchild2" label="SubChild 2" />
  <s:treenode theme="ajax" id="subchild3" label="SubChild 3" />
  </s:treenode>
  <s:treenode theme="ajax" id="child2" label="<b>child 2</b>" />
 </s:tree>
```

but it is not displaying  s value in

```
<s:tree theme="ajax" id="root" label="%{s}">
```

please suggest me how to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: Using scriptlets is a very bad practice, use taglibs instead.

But if you really need this then use `<s:set>` tag to assign variable.

```
<%
 String s="ROOT";
%>
<s:set var="sVar">
  <%=s %>
</s:set>
<sj:tree theme="ajax" id="root" label="%{#sVar}">
```

BTW there is no such thing as `tree` in `/struts-tags` you probably mean `/struts-jquery-tags`.